# geolocation in html5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

how to get current latitude and longitude in asp.net. i have this code, but it didn't return data. it's not fall alert

```
  <script type='text/javascript' language="javascript">
    function getUserLock() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayResult, displayError);
        }
        else {
            setMessage("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
        }
    }

    function displayResult(position) {         
        setMessage("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        PageMethods.SendLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, onComplete, onFailed);
        alert ('test');
    }

    function setMessage(msg) {
        //            document.forms[0].myLoc.value = msg;
    }

    function displayError(error) {
        var errors = { 1: 'Permission denied', 2: 'Position unavailable', 3: 'Request timeout' };
        setMessage("Error occured: " + errors[error.code]);
    }

    function onComplete(args) {
        if (args)
            alert('Log in oldunuz');
        else
            alert('İşlem Başarısız Oldu. Yeniden Deneyiniz...');
    }

    function onFailed(error) {
        alert('Yapılan işlem sırasında aşağıdaki hata(lar) oluştu.\n\r' + error.get_message());
    }

</script>
```

this is button

```
 <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"
                OnClientClick="getUserLock();" OnClick="LoginButton_Click" />
```

Comment: If you put in an alert, does your javascript get the latitude and longitude?  That would be the best starting point.

Comment: i try it, but it's not falled. firstly user click myLogIn button, browser ask allow or deny. but in one second, it automatically disappear

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with latitude or longitude then?

Comment: if i allow, i can take latitude or longitude.. but it disappear one second

Comment: So you have two problems?  You will need to use a javascript debugger to see what is going on, then you can go back to the .NET code to see what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several issues here:

**In order to be able to use PageMethods container in JavaScript you need to**

First, decorate your method with [WebMethod] attribute. You are only allowed to use the static methods!

```
[WebMethod]
public static string HelloWorld(string name)
{
   return “Hello, World. I am ” + name;
}
```

Second, enable the support for PageMethods

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID=”ScriptManager1″ runat=”server” EnablePageMethods=”True” />
```

I would also add some support for error handling by providing the appropriate function handlers to the function: every invocation from PageMethods takes parameters for possible outcomes of the invocations as well as some other parameters.

Comment: i also added these. but still, i can not take these datas. i debug it, but breakpoint's not falled. (sorry my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to add timeout(default time out is infinite) so that you can get error message

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayResult, displayError,{timeout:10000});
```